# scipy fmin operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mle

i'm trying to learn about optimization in Python so i've written some code to test out the fmin function.

However i keep receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (100,)
```

I can tell the issue is to do with the dimensions of my arguments but I'm not sure how to rectify it. Rather than a lambda function I also tried to def a function but I still get the same error.

I'm sure it's something pretty basic but I can't seem to understand it. Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.distributions import norm
from scipy.optimize import fmin

x = np.random.normal(size=100)

norm_1 = lambda theta,x: -(np.log(norm.pdf(x,theta[0],theta[1]))).sum()

def norm_2(theta,x):
    mu = theta[0]
    sigma = theta[1]
    ll = np.log(norm.pdf(x,mu,sigma)).sum()
    return -ll

fmin(norm_1,np.array([0,1]),x)

fmin(norm_2,np.array([0,1]),x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs for fmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) say:

```
Definition: fmin(func, x0, args=(), xtol=0.0001, ftol=0.0001, maxiter=None, maxfun=None, full_output=0, disp=1, retall=0, callback=None)
...
    args : tuple, optional
        Extra arguments passed to func, i.e. ``f(x,*args)``.
```

Therefore, the third argument, `args`, should be a tuple:

```
In [45]: fmin(norm_1,np.array([0,1]),(x,))
Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.
Out[45]: array([-0.02405078,  1.0203125 ])
```

`(x, )` is a tuple containing one element, `x`. 
The docs say `f(x, *args)` gets called. Which mean in your case

```
norm_1(np.array([0,1]), *(x,))
```

will get called, which [is equivalent to](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)

```
norm_1(np.array([0,1]), x)
```